# On hover thumbnail change main image with jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, gallery, thumbnails, onchange

I'm looking for something like [this](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/5/) where if I hover the thumbnail the main image is changing. But there is a problem because I need also something like fancybox - on click main image or thumbnail will show large image. Also there should be fotogallery of thumbnails in one line and if there will be more than for example four thumbnails then there will be arrow right/left for move gallery. Is there any solution that contain all my requirements?

Answer (score 10):

try this :

```
var mainImage = $("#mainImage");
$(".img-container img").hover(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#mainImage").attr("src",src);
});

mainImage.on("click",function(){
   $(this).css("transform","scale(2)");
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RyDqX/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a collection of solutions check and find the right one
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/

Comment: Thanks but I don't want any slider or something like this because I need change image on hover and not on click.

Comment: Its not just sliders its galleries as well like this one http://www.tn3gallery.com/?refCode=fe8775 you just change the width of it